# android- how to get the start date and end date of last week of the current month

Tags: android

I am trying to get last week start date and end date from current date.
And in my application week starts on Monday. For that I am using

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 2);
```

Comment: How does your code relate to getting start & end date ?

Comment: Check my answer below. It will help you out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
    protected void getpreviousweek(int num) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                // Set the calendar to monday of the current week
                c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);
                c.add(Calendar.DATE, num * 7);
                // Print dates of the current week starting on Monday
                DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
                ArrayList<String> listDate = new ArrayList<String>();

                           for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) 
                        {
                             listDate.add(df.format(c.getTime()));
                             c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
                        } 
         }
```

Pass num = -1 and check. You will get all the days of previous week. If you want first and last date then

```
String startDate =listDate.get(0);
String endDate = listDate.get(6);    // do this after for loop.
```

Comment: Just copy my code and check. It should work. I have tested it.

Comment: Let me know the result.

Comment: Please up vote the answer. It will be useful for others having same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Calendar for do this:

```
Date date = new Date();
Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
calendar.setTime(date);

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MMM dd HH:mm:ss");    

int year       = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int month      = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH); // Jan = 0, dec = 11
int dayOfMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); 
int dayOfWeek  = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
int weekOfYear = calendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
int weekOfMonth= calendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH);

System.out.println(sdf.format(calendar.getTime()));

System.out.println("year \t\t: " + year);
System.out.println("month \t\t: " + month);
System.out.println("dayOfMonth \t: " + dayOfMonth);
System.out.println("dayOfWeek \t: " + dayOfWeek);
System.out.println("weekOfYear \t: " + weekOfYear);
System.out.println("weekOfMonth \t: " + weekOfMonth);
```

if you know the the current day of the week you can calculate the last and the first day.

For example subtract 5 days:

```
calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -5);
```